# Multiple Google maps with markers on same page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to insert 3 different google maps into a page on a website and also include markers.

The following script places the google map with marker in a div named #william_harvey. I then want two additional and different maps to display with markers in other divs named #chaucer and #kims but can't get this to work. Any advice?

```
 <script>
 function initMap() {
      var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
      var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('william_harvey'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }
        </script>
        <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: What does your code look like where you tried to add multiple maps?  What are the coordinates for the other maps?

Comment: id originally copied the code three times which before I added the markers worked perfectly but since adding the markers it no longer works.

Comment: here are the three id's and their actual map references:

william_harvey - 51.143183, 0.915349
chaucer - 51.261797, 1.087446
kims - 51.286869, 0.556317

Comment: That should work. What did that code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make 3 separate `google.maps.Map` objects, three separate `google.maps.Marker` objects and add each marker to its associated map.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chtpafm8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var william_harvey = {
  lat: 51.143183,
  lng: 0.915349
};
var chaucer = {
  lat: 51.261797,
  lng: 1.087446
};
var kims = {
  lat: 51.286869,
  lng: 0.556317
};

function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: -25.363,
    lng: 131.044
  };
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('william_harvey'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: william_harvey
  });
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: william_harvey,
    map: map1,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('chaucer'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: chaucer
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: chaucer,
    map: map2,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });
  var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('kims'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: kims
  });
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: kims,
    map: map3,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#william_harvey,
#chaucer,
#kims {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="william_harvey" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="chaucer" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="kims" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

initMap convert function with parameter mapId. Then call the function with div id.
Like this:

```
function mapCreate(id)
{
      var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
      var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng
      });
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map1,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
}

mapCreate('chaucer');
mapCreate('kims');
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egvrcn/yL91bpsg/1/)

If you different behave maps, use arrays.

Comment: how would I apply this if each map has a different longitude and latitude reference?